# Solve for $x$ given $2.544 = e^{-x} + e^{-2x} + e^{-3x}$

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

Can this problem be solved algebraically? $$e^{-x}+e^{-2x} + e^{-3x} = 2.544$$

Comment: The short answer is: yes.

Comment: is the number 2.544 exact or an approximation from, for example, an experiment?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Let $e^{-x}=u$ to get  $$u+u^2+u^3=2.544$$
when $0<u\le 1$

Comment: Is the next step factoring it? I cannot figure out how to factor this, since it doesn't involve only integers.

Comment: @MiltonFriedman you can find a real root by trial and error method or by any others methods then you can reduce the degree of equation by using the long division to find the others roots

Comment: Or you can link to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E3%2By%5E2%2By%3D2.544), like gimusi did.

Comment: Or you can do full [Cardano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) on it (because it's a cubic).

Answer (score 2):

Let $$y=e^{-x}\quad 0<y\le 1$$

then solve

$$y^3+y^2+y=2.544$$

then $$-x=\ln y \implies x=\ln \frac 1y$$

To prove rigorously that there is only a (real) solution we can consider

$$f(y)=y^3+y^2+y-2.544$$

which is continuous with $f(0)<0$, $f(1)>0$, $f'(x)>0$ and refer to [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Our dear friend [Wolfy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E3%2By%5E2%2By%3D2.544) can help to find the numerical value for that solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85214/discussion-on-answer-by-gimusi-solve-for-x-given-2-544-e-x-e-2x-e).